# warden authentication returning 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, warden

`warden.authenticate!(auth_options)`

working fine for these params:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"5BMAUoZLUEgPZBVOAcQ8lFD4+pumP9kEvvXyelbnjeO36AZJQt2oRlraicQ6quvh/dccS0ELUkxjACgFcWFYAg==",
>   "user"=>{"email"=>"vijay@xyz.com", "password"=>"xyz",
>   "phone"=>"9443429932"}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"sessions",
>   "format"=>"json", "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"vijay@xyz.com",
>   "password"=>"xyz", "phone"=>"9443429932"}}}

but failing for these:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"/ly2phwfsD3HEVkHK39ajYQGv6R4uj2z3B+3eiZEU0qtp7C92IlIM5KvxY0QEY34KSlZdJ+OtvsB6m0FAcKGqw==",
>   "user"=>{"phone"=>"9443429932", "password"=>"xyz",
>   "email"=>"vijay@xyz.com"}, "action"=>"create",
>   "controller"=>"sessions", "format"=>"json",
>   "session"=>{"user"=>{"phone"=>"9443429932", "password"=>"xyz",
>   "email"=>"vijay@xyz.com"}}}

The data is the same in both cases except for the order.
Stuck with this for long.

here is the log:

> Started POST "/users/sign_in.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-10
>   10:53:07 +0530 Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"XVMbYLTgv4eFbv9pX5lJD3U6DHF17o18rVIjqQLo4skOqB17cHZHidDQY+Nk95562BXqoZLaBjRwp/nWJW43KA==",
>   "user"=>{"phone"=>"9443429932", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
>   "session"=>{"user"=>{"phone"=>"9443429932",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM
>   `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 12422916 AND (invitation_token is null)
>   LIMIT 1 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue.
warden is reading the params from request.params
I have edited the params, but it was not reflecting in request.params.

`request.params[:user].merge!(params[:user])`

This fixed the issue.